# Handling significant (but meaningless) constant changes in .IML files for shared IntelliJ project

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a relatively simple 3-module IntelliJ project built using Gradle. I'm new to both Gradle and IntelliJ, and am working on getting the tooling/process understood between two of my personal machines.

The projects are stored in Git, but every time I open IntelliJ on one of my respective machines (after pushing changes from the other) my module files are always changed:

```
modified:   .idea/modules/core/core.iml
modified:   .idea/modules/service/service.iml
modified:   .idea/modules/web/web.iml
```

The changes are always just the reordering of my library entries:

```
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.6.Final" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: io.projectreactor:reactor-core:2.0.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.15" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.jodd:jodd-core:3.7.1" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2" level="project" />
-    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0" level="project" />
     <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.jodd:jodd-core:3.7.1" level="project" />
+    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.15" level="project" />
```

And the changes are significant:

```
$ git diff --stat
 java/.idea/modules/core/core.iml       | 204 ++++++++++----------
 java/.idea/modules/service/service.iml | 276 +++++++++++++--------------
 java/.idea/modules/web/web.iml         | 338 ++++++++++++++++-----------------
```

This happens every time I swap from one machine to the other.

**Is there any way** to convince IntelliJ to keep these entries in the same order? It's getting extremely annoying for each one of my commits to have these 3 files included along with whatever other changes I'm making.

I obviously can't `.gitignore` these three files, as they contain all the other information *about my module*'s configuration - something that it completely makes sense to share.

Note that I'm not using `apply plugin 'idea'` in my build files, I'm just letting IDEA manage the modules entirely. Is this my mistake?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91607.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I obviously can't `.gitignore` these three files, as they contain all
>   the other information *about my module*'s configuration - something
>   that it completely makes sense to share.

Actually, you can. These files will be generated from Gradle when you open the project and Synchronize it with Gradle.

See the [FAQ about sharing project files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) and the comments below.

Related bugs:

- [IDEA-165941](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165941) Gradle: orderEntry's in .iml are sorted differently on Refresh with and without change in build.gradle
- [IDEA-157363](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157363) Android: arbitrarily reordering of orderEntry tags in iml files w/o related changes in gradle configuration

Comment: So there's no information stored in these `.iml` files by IDEA, it's all completely generated by IntelliJ's Gradle integration? (I don't need to add `apply plugin 'idea'` to my `build.gradle`?)

Comment: Yes, `idea` plug-in is not needed and `.iml` files are generated from Gradle model.